# Getting the previous element of a IOrderedEnumeration

Tags: entity-framework, collections

I have a enumeration of objects :

```
    public IOrderedEnumerable<RentContract> Contracts {
        get { return RentContracts.OrderByDescending(rc => rc.DateCreated); }
    }
```

I have to compare a given RentContract instance with its previous RenContract instance on the list to highlight changes between the two objects, which is the most correct method to get the previous element ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible directly. You can do it like this:

```
var input = new SomeClass[10]; //test data
var zipped = input.Zip(new SomeClass[1].Concat(input), (a, b) => { a, b });
var result = zipped.Where(x => x.b == null || x.a.DateCreated < x.b.DateCreated.AddHours(-1)); //some example
```

This solution is zipping the sequence with itself, but offset by one null element.